# Why do I keep getting "undefined reference to" error in my program?

Tags: c

I'm new to c, and for my assignment we have to calculate how much money to charge using a function. However, I keep getting "undefined reference to `Calculate_charge'" whenever I try to call the function. what exactly am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

double Calculate_charge(double y);

int main(void)
{

    int customer;
    double charge = 0;
    int kwh;
    double totalcharge;
    int totalkwh;
    int totalcustomer;
    unsigned int count;

    customer = 0;
    kwh= 0;
    totalcharge = 0;
    totalkwh = 0;
    totalcustomer = 0;
    count = 0;

    printf( "%s","Enter customer number (-1 to quit):\n");
    scanf("%d", &customer);
    printf("%s", "Enter kwh used (-1 to quit):\n");
    scanf("%d", &kwh);

    while (customer != -1 && kwh != -1) {
        Calculate_charge(charge);
        printf( "Customer Num: %d\n", customer);
        printf("KWH used: %d\n", kwh);
        printf("Charge: %.2f\n", charge);
        count++;
        totalcustomer++;
        totalcharge = totalcharge + charge;
        totalkwh = totalkwh + kwh;

        printf( "%s","Enter customer number (-1 to quit):\n");
        scanf("%d", &customer);
        printf("%s", "Enter kwh used (-1 to quit):\n");
        scanf("%d", &kwh);  
        }

    double Calculate_charge(double y)
    {
        if (kwh <= 300) {
            y = .09 * kwh;  
        }
        else if (kwh > 300 &&  kwh <= 600){
            y = .08 * kwh;
        }
        else if (kwh > 600 && kwh <= 1000){
            y = .06 *kwh;
        }
        else {
            y = .05 * kwh;
        }
        return y;
    }

    if (count != 0) {

        printf("\n");
        printf("Total customers:%d\n", totalcustomer);
        printf("Total KWH used: %d\n", totalkwh);
        printf("Total Charged: %.2f" , totalcharge);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you copy/paste the exact error message you get?

Comment: The exact error message is: (.text+0x94): undefined reference to `Calculate_charge'

Comment: You've nested the code for `Calculate_charge()` inside `main()`.  That is ***not*** standard C, though GCC recognizes nested functions if you're careful.  (The error message means you're not being careful enough.)  I neither know nor care what the rules are — nested functions are not C.  (If I want Algol, or Pascal, I'll use them.) . You can find the docs at [Nested Functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.3.0/gcc/Nested-Functions.html#Nested-Functions).  You'd do best to move the function definition outside `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the function before it's declared. Either forward declare it and declare it after or move the declaration to before `main()`.

What you've done in your code is forward declare it and then declare it *inside `main()`* which is not the correct place for that code.

It should be *outside* of the main function.

The easiest fix here is to eliminate the forward declaration and declare the function right there instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double Calculate_charge(double y)
{
    if (kwh <= 300) {
        y = .09 * kwh;  
    }
    else if (kwh > 300 &&  kwh <= 600){
        y = .08 * kwh;
    }
    else if (kwh > 600 && kwh <= 1000){
        y = .06 *kwh;
    }
    else {
        y = .05 * kwh;
    }
    return y;
}

int main() {
  // ...

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "declare the function right there instead"? I had to read this multiple times to understand what you are trying to say and I have some experience with C++. I expect that to a beginner it might be unclear.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice As in move the declaration that's presently in the middle of `main()` to the exact spot where the forward declaration is right now. Added an example for clarification.

Comment: The `Calculate_charge()` function is _defined_ inside `main()` — there'd be a semicolon after the prototype line if it was just a declaration.  So, the code in the question is using GCC's [nested functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.3.0/gcc/Nested-Functions.html#Nested-Functions) (mis)feature — probably unwittingly.